# Installing an IPv6 subnet to my home network

Tags: windows, networking, router, ipv6, pfsense

When I call my ISP and ask for an IPv6 subnet which the default is a /64, correct?

I have the ability to then assign an IPv6 address or more to each one of my servers, which is 20 in total, and they will be accessible to the internet correct?

I have a pfSense box running with my modem in bridge mode so do I need to route my Ipv6's to my boxes?

Comment: ISPs are free to assign anywhere from (usually) a /48 to a /64 to a leaf site. How are we supposed to know what your particular ISP does?

Comment: Does the size that they assign effect assigning locally to every machine?

Comment: No. You'd still be using /64s locally, unless you plan on playing with routing between subnets, but a larger leaf site allocation (say, a /60) would allow subnet separation, which a /64 doesn't.